# EKEvent incorrect date when allday is set

Tags: ekevent, weekday

If today is Tuesday 2PM May 6th

```
event.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
event.allDay = YES;
[dateFormat setDateFormat:EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy];
NSString* dayStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:event.startDate];
timeDetails.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\nAll day", dayStr];
```

results in Monday May 5th

same code without allDay set

```
event.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy];
NSString* dayStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:event.startDate];
timeDetails.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\nAll day", dayStr];
```

results in Tuesday May 6th which is correct.
Anyone has any clues?

Answer (score 11):

**Background**

In iOS all dates have a time component. So for an all day event, some time is still used. Typically this is midnight to "just before" midnight (23:59), giving the event a span of almost 24 hours.

The challenge comes with timezones and daylight saving. This can mean thats all day events start at 11pm the previous day and finish at 22:59. It all depends on where you are viewing the event from. Unfortunately in iOS development this often isn't clear! I've had some really "fun" bug that only materialise when running the app between 11pm and midnight before.

**Fix**

Amazingly the behaviour of EKEvent changes according the order that you set the properties. If you set event.allDay = YES **before** you set the startDate then you will get the behaviour you are expecting.

Comment: I tried to set `event.isAllDat = true` in Swift 3.
But, there's still the same problem.

Comment: Amazing that order of the statements is important here. It solved my issue. event.allDay = YES must be defined prior to the start/end dates definition

Answer (score 1):

It may be related to timezone. Cannot confirm it though, since even if I try setting formatter timezone it still produces the same problem. More importantly I would have assumed that if I create NSData and use NSFormatter on it by default it would all match.

Comment: you're correct on the timezone relation - when not set, the all-day flag works properly again